# Finding a value from one row in another row

Tags: python

I currently have two spread sheets and I need to find the value from one row and match it up to another row.  My code is:

```
with open('design_products_view.csv') as design_file, open('templates_view.csv') as templates:
    designs = csv.reader(design_file, delimiter=',')
    template_files = csv.reader(templates, delimiter=',')
    containsProduct = "Circle"

    for row in designs:
        if containsProduct in row[1]:
            rowValue = row[1].split(' ')[0]
            for row in template_files:
                if row[1] != "width":
                    print(rowValue)
                    if rowValue in row[1]:
                        print('found')
```

I compare the values from two csvs.  The issue I'm having is that one csv `rowValue` displays an escape back slash like so:

```
1.0\
1.0\
1.0\
1.0\
1.0\
1.0\
```

When I check if this value `rowValue` is in `row[1]` it doesn't match up.
In example `rowValue is 1.0\` and `row[1] is 1.00`
Any idea how I can accomplish this?
I also attempted to remove the backspace escape with:

```
rowValue = row[1].split('/')[0]
```

Sample data:
templates_view.csv

```
"id","width","height","attribute_item_id","created_at","updated_at","design_id"
2584,1.50,0.50,10,"2022-01-27 17:52:22","2022-01-27 17:52:22",NULL
2585,1.50,0.50,10,"2022-01-27 17:52:22","2022-01-27 17:52:22",NULL
2586,2.00,0.50,10,"2022-01-27 17:52:22","2022-01-27 17:52:22",NULL
2587,2.00,0.50,10,"2022-01-27 17:52:22","2022-01-27 17:52:22",NULL
2588,2.50,0.50,10,"2022-01-27 17:52:22","2022-01-27 17:52:22",NULL
2589,2.50,0.50,10,"2022-01-27 17:52:22","2022-01-27 17:52:22",NULL
2590,3.00,0.50,10,"2022-01-27 17:52:22","2022-01-27 17:52:22",NULL
2591,3.00,0.50,10,"2022-01-27 17:52:22","2022-01-27 17:52:22",NULL
```

design_products_view.csv

```
"id","name","price","product","thumbnail","thumbnail_url","template","description","active_description","stages","variations","attributes","printings","order","active","author","created","updated","template_id"
15,"1.0\" Circle",0,0,"thumbnails/lumise-media-01_round-curled-sticker-PacerPlaceholder-12.png","https://design.pacerlabels.com/data/thumbnails/eRsp0afJYlN2.png","","Available in White BOPP - Clear BOPP - Silver Metallic BOPP - Holographic Metallic BOPP and Kraft.",0,"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","JTdCJTIyZGVmYXVsdCUyMiUzQSUyMiUyMiUyQyUyMmF0dHJzJTIyJTNBJTVCJTVEJTJDJTIydmFyaWF0aW9ucyUyMiUzQSU3QiU3RCU3RA==","JTdCJTdE","%7B%7D",0,1,"","2022-02-11 22:38:44","2022-03-17 23:26:52",NULL
16,"1.063\" Circle",0,0,"thumbnails/lumise-media-01_round-curled-sticker-PacerPlaceholder-13.png","https://design.pacerlabels.com/data/thumbnails/YSAsea9cRpdz.png","","Available in White BOPP - Clear BOPP - Silver Metallic BOPP - Holographic Metallic BOPP and Kraft.",0,"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","JTdCJTIyZGVmYXVsdCUyMiUzQSUyMiUyMiUyQyUyMmF0dHJzJTIyJTNBJTVCJTVEJTJDJTIydmFyaWF0aW9ucyUyMiUzQSU3QiU3RCU3RA==","JTdCJTdE","%7B%7D",0,1,"","2022-02-11 23:09:44","2022-03-17 23:27:00",NULL
17,"1.125\" Circle",0,0,"thumbnails/lumise-media-01_round-curled-sticker-PacerPlaceholder-14.png","https://design.pacerlabels.com/data/thumbnails/HREyNGId87lO.png","","Available in White BOPP - Clear BOPP - Silver Metallic BOPP - Holographic Metallic BOPP and Kraft.",0,"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","JTdCJTIyZGVmYXVsdCUyMiUzQSUyMiUyMiUyQyUyMmF0dHJzJTIyJTNBJTVCJTVEJTJDJTIydmFyaWF0aW9ucyUyMiUzQSU3QiU3RCU3RA==","JTdCJTdE","%7B%7D",0,1,"","2022-02-11 23:14:53","2022-03-17 23:27:09",NULL
```

Comment: can you provide sample data from your csv file? it looks like line breaks are messing up with your algorithm.

Comment: @Bruno added the sample data, thank you!

Comment: `design_products_view.csv` actually has that backslash after the number in column 2. I'm not sure `"1.063\" Circle"` is valid CSV, isn't it supposed to be `"1.063"" Circle"` instead, doubling double quotes in the middle of a field, rather than escaping them?

Comment: in the db it's 1.063" which is why I think on the export it escapes them.  I guess it's just removing them from the csv first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, firstly I'd recommend you to normalized your data, meaning: remove the '' slash from your csv file before processing it, if it's not possible, below you'll see a working example of your code and I think you've missed the double '\' because you'll need to escape it before comparing the values:

```
import csv

with open('design_products_view.csv') as design_file, open('templates_view.csv') as templates:
    designs = csv.reader(design_file, delimiter=',')
    template_files = csv.reader(templates, delimiter=',')
    containsProduct = "Circle"

    for row in designs:
        if containsProduct in row[1]:
            rowValue = row[1].split('\\')[0] # Note the '\\'
            for row in template_files:
                if row[1] != "width":
                    print(rowValue)
                    if rowValue in row[1]:
                            print('found')
```

I've used the data (templates_view.csv) sample below by adding one more row with a '1.00' value to exemplify the solution.

```
"id","width","height","attribute_item_id","created_at","updated_at","design_id"
2584,1.50,0.50,10,"2022-01-27 17:52:22","2022-01-27 17:52:22",NULL
2585,1.50,0.50,10,"2022-01-27 17:52:22","2022-01-27 17:52:22",NULL
2586,2.00,0.50,10,"2022-01-27 17:52:22","2022-01-27 17:52:22",NULL
2587,2.00,0.50,10,"2022-01-27 17:52:22","2022-01-27 17:52:22",NULL
2588,2.50,0.50,10,"2022-01-27 17:52:22","2022-01-27 17:52:22",NULL
2589,2.50,0.50,10,"2022-01-27 17:52:22","2022-01-27 17:52:22",NULL
2590,3.00,0.50,10,"2022-01-27 17:52:22","2022-01-27 17:52:22",NULL
2591,3.00,0.50,10,"2022-01-27 17:52:22","2022-01-27 17:52:22",NULL
2591,1.00,0.50,10,"2022-01-27 17:52:22","2022-01-27 17:52:22",NULL
```